# Can't access NSString from another class — Objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with some names in it. I have built my app from the MasterViewController template that Apple provides. I'm trying to store the name of the selected cell in a `NSString` and then access it in the other class that handles the new `ViewController` that appears when the cell is tapped. In there I use that string as the title of the view.

In `MasterViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theTitle;
```

In `MasterViewController.m`

```
@synthesize theTitle;

- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    theTitle = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

In the new ViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.m"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MasterViewController* MasterViewControllerAccess = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    self.title = MasterViewControllerAccess.theTitle;
    NSLog("%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", MasterViewControllerAccess.theTitle]);
}
```

The new ViewController is linked to the cell in the IB. When I press the cell `theTitle` returns `NULL`. But if I log it directly in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`method it returns the real names. This means that something wrong occurs between the different classes. What's wrong?

Comment: how did you push ViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a new instance of `MasterViewController`, instead you need to access the `MasterViewController` instance that already exists. Consider following Apple's example of setting the detail item (ie from master to detail). I can't see any reason to set it the way you are doing it. In any case, if you are using a navigation controller:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h" // don't import .m files. Always import .h files

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MasterViewController* MasterViewControllerAccess = (MasterViewController*)self.navigationController.viewControllers[0]
    self.title = MasterViewControllerAccess.theTitle;
    NSLog("%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", MasterViewControllerAccess.theTitle]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `viewDidLoad` of the pushed view controller, you allocate a new instance
of `MasterViewController`, which is completely different and unrelated to the
existing master view controller (which has been loaded from the storyboard or nib file).
Therefore `MasterViewControllerAccess.theTitle` is `nil`.

As said in the above comments, it is usually easier to pass the information the other way
around (from master to detail view controller), e.g. in `prepareForSegue` as in
the template application.